# Delete mysql record using delete button

Tags: php, mysql

im sure many of you have seen this question before, ive applied the code that worked for others to my own and still nothing, I'm finding it hard to identify whats going wrong. Here is my user side with the table displaying the mysql info and delete buttons:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "gpdb";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT AppID, AppDate FROM appointment WHERE PatientID ='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo ("<form  action='delete.php' method='post'><table class='jobs-list'>
<tr>
<th class='job-position'><h4>Appointment ID</h4></th>
<th class='job-position'><h4>Appointment Date and Time</h4></th>
<th class='job-position'><h4>Edit Appointments</h4></th>
</tr>");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo ('<tr>');
echo ('<td>' . $row['AppID'] . '</td>');
echo ('<td>' . $row['AppDate'] . '</td>');
echo ("<td><input type='submit' id='deleteItem' value='".$row['AppID']."'/>   </td>");
echo ('</tr>');
}
echo ('</table></form>');

}
else{
echo('<h4><b>You currently have no appointments</b></h4>');
}
?>
<script>

$('#deleteItem').on('click', function(){
var pass = $(this).val(); 
console.log(pass);
$.post( "delete.php", { 
    'pass':pass
}).done(function( data ) {
    alert( "You cancelled : " + data );
});
});
</script>
```

And this is the delete.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
//$servername = "localhost";
//$username = "root";
//$password = "";
//$dbname = "gpdb";
//$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//if ($conn->connect_error) {
//die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 //}
 print_r($_POST['pass']);
//if(isset($_POST['pass']) && $_POST['pass'] != "")
//{ 
//$deleteItem = $_POST['pass'];
//$sql = "DELETE FROM appointment WHERE AppID='{$deleteItem}'";
//$result = $conn->query($sql);
//header("location: http://localhost/gp/account.php");
//}else{
//echo('Something wrong');
//}

?>
```

I am currently reading "something wrong" on the delete.php so there is no return coming from the delete.php.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: its because you are accessing variable  `deleteItem` which is not posted from ajax, it should be `pass`.. in IF condition and query of delete

Comment: Sorry, I've been playing about with so much i dont cant even see the little things anymore, ive chnaged these back as you can see but am still recieving the error.

Comment: Also you can not use `and`  in IF condition use && instead of it..

Comment: I have posted and edited answer and you will just need to copy and paste it and you are done

Answer (score 1):

This condition is your enemy

`if(isset($_POST['deleteItem']) and is_numeric($_POST['deleteItem']))`

since `$_POST['deleteItem']` is not numeric , because the value is something like `Delete 1` that's why you always see "Something Wrong"

Comment: Thank you, I just toook this from something i seen on here i have changed it to :
if(isset($_POST['pass']))
although still reciving error

Comment: There is nothing in $_POST['pass']. You need to set your HTML button and give it the id "pass"

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your code.

you shoud echo the button like this :

```
echo ("<td><input type='button' class='deleteItem' name='delete_".$row['AppID']."' value='".$row['AppID']."'/>")
```

And you should not use php variable in your javascript, your javascript should be like this

```
<script>

$('.deleteItem').on('click', function(){
    var pass = $(this).val(); 
    $.post( "delete.php", { 
        'pass':pass
    }).done(function( data ) {
        alert( "You cancelled : " + data );
    });
});
</script>
```

Then in your delete.php you should check for `$_POST['pass']` NOT `$_POST['deleteItem']`

So the code will be

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "gpdb";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
if(isset($_POST['pass']) && is_numeric($_POST['pass']))
 {
$deleteItem = $_POST['pass'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM appointment WHERE AppID='{$deleteItem}'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
header("location: http://localhost/gp/account.php");
}else{
echo('Something wrong');
}

?>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I have applied all these changes to my original question, I really thought the issue was related to the variable gathered in the post, however im still getting the error. Is it ok that im passing $row['AppID'] from the button when it already exists previously in the table? I thought this might cause confusion but it appears that how these questions have been previously answered?

Comment: I just realized that you echo button inside a loop, so there will be an array of buttons with same ID and Name, I've modified the code a bit. Try this, if your are still getting error we will debug the `delete.php`

Comment: Yes still getting the error... how can i debug delete.php?

Comment: echo `$_POST['pass']` and see what you are getting at `delete.php`

Comment: I recieving the error:
Undefined index: pass in C:\wamp\www\gp\delete.php on line 12.
so im assuming nothings being posted...

Comment: ok can you `alert(pass)` after `var pass` in your javascript?

Comment: I did this and tested but its skipping straight to the error on delete.php... skipping over the alert or the alerts not holding anything?

Comment: Would this be because im calling the class='deleteItem' in $('.deleteItem').on('click', function(){ instead of the name='delete_".$row['AppID']."' and should name be id?

Comment: just comment the `$.post()` do only alert.

Comment: you can't have more than one html element with same id and if you put same name for many elements then the value will be an array of values of all elements with that name.

Comment: ok, i am now recieving the alert with the correct value for each button.

Comment: If i try to `print_r($_POST['pass']);` pass is not being recognised, when i write `print_r($_POST); ` i can see the following:
`Array ( [delete_20] => 20 )`, how can i get the value from the array?

Comment: change the button type to `button` and see what you are getting on delete.php `print_r('$_POST')`

Comment: i resolved the issue, posted an answer with the final code, thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your'e using button type submit it will reload the page.Check the code below use `event.preventDefault();` or else change the `submit` type to `button`

```
<script>
$('#deleteItem').on('click', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
var pass = $row['AppID']; 
$.post( "delete.php", {  'pass':pass }).done(function( data ) {
alert( "You cancelled : " + data );
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

finally resolved the issue, thanks for all your help, especially @Gopakumar Gopalan. I really needed that posting call but it seemed that the form method was holding the function back so i deleted the form tags from the table:

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "gpdb";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT AppID, AppDate FROM appointment WHERE PatientID ='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo ("<table class='jobs-list'>
<tr>
<th class='job-position'><h4>Appointment ID</h4></th>
<th class='job-position'><h4>Appointment Date and Time</h4></th>
<th class='job-position'><h4>Edit Appointments</h4></th>
</tr>");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo ('<tr>');
echo ('<td>' . $row['AppID'] . '</td>');
echo ('<td>' . $row['AppDate'] . '</td>');
echo ("<td><input type='submit' class='deleteItem'    name='delete_".$row['AppID']."' value='".$row['AppID']."'/></td>");
echo ('</tr>');
}
echo ('</table>');

}
else{
echo('<h4><b>You currently have no appointments</b></h4>');
}
?>
<script>

$('.deleteItem').on('click', function(){
var pass = $(this).val();
$.post( "delete.php", { 
   'pass':pass
}).done(function( data ) {
   location.reload();
});
});
</script>
```

Once the form tags were removed the delete.php file could recognise the $_POST['pass']; :

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "gpdb";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if(isset($_POST['pass']) && $_POST['pass'] != "")
{ 
$deleteItem = $_POST['pass'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM appointment WHERE AppID='{$deleteItem}'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
header("location: http://localhost/gp/account.php");
}else{
echo('Something wrong');
}

?>
```

Hopefully this answer can help someone else as well. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

First thing the #deleteItem means you are accesing and firing event in id and there is no id with such name in the page

Second if you will put the id="deleteItem" in loop there will be multiple id with same name that is wrong

what you can do is send the id in a function it will send the exact id for the row the delete button is clicked

```
<input type='button' name='deleteItem' value='Delete" onclick="deleteSelected('" .$row['AppID']."')'/>
```

Now inside the function call the ajax as below

```
<script>
    function deleteSelected(delete_id)
    {
        $.post( "delete.php", { 
       'deleteItem':delete_id
        }).done(function( data ) {
    alert( "You cancelled : " + data );
        });
    }
</script>
```

Now change the if condition on the action page to

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteItem']) && is_numeric($_POST['deleteItem']))
{
$deleteItem = $_POST['deleteItem'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM appointment WHERE AppID='{$deleteItem}'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
header("location: http://localhost/gp/account.php");
}else{
echo('Something wrong');
}
```

Comment: Dont know why my answer is donvoted a comment will be helpful while downvoting

Comment: Hi I've tried this but im not getting anything now, before it went to the delete.php and i seen the error but there was no return but now nothing...

Comment: @NiamhMacGualraic HI can you please see in console and post the error